# Getting Error -function not define in my script

Tags: javascript, html, css

there is the link below please have a look on code I am having issue in my function even I defined it and calling it but its saying function is defined but not used.

```
function addDnDHandlers() {
    var coffeeimages = document.getElementsByClassName("productarticlewide");
    var shoppingcartDropZone = document.getElementById("shoppingcart");
    var shoppingcart = document.querySelectorAll("#shoppingcart ul")[0];

    for (var i = 0; i <= coffeeimages; i++) {
        coffeeimages[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", this.getAttribute("id"));
        }, false);
    }

    shoppingcartDropZone.addEventListener("dragover", function (ev) {
        if (ev.preventDefault) ev.preventDefault();
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
        return false;
    }, false);

    shoppingcartDropZone.addEventListener("drop", function (ev) {
        if (ev.stopPropagation) ev.stopPropagation();

        var coffeeId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var element = document.getElementById(coffeeId);
        addCoffeeToShoppingCart(element, coffeeId);
        ev.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }, false);

    function addCoffeeToShoppingCart(item, id) {
        var html = id + " " + item.getAttribute("data-price");
        var liElement = document.createElement('li');
        liElement.innerHTML = html;
        shoppingcart.appendChild(liElement);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b435pekf/

Comment: Pleas include the code in the post, and the link you provided does not link to any code (just the jsfiddle.net home page).

Comment: Please post the code here. If you are going to provide a link, you should ensure it works.

Comment: The link you gave leads to `jsFiddle.net` which is of no use to any person. Provide a __working link__ to __your__ code or better still post your code here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b435pekf/

Comment: I've added the code from your fiddle, and updated the link, but you need to be more specific about the error message you are receiving (which function is not "being used?" And the title suggests a run-time error that the function is not defined, while your description suggests a linting error that the function IS defined, but not called.

Comment: its  this one "addDnDHandlers()"

Comment: ESLint : ERROR: 'addDnDHandlers' is defined but never used. [no-unused-vars] function addDnDHandlers() {

Comment: That's just a linting error since ESLint can't pick up that your function is being called on DOMContentLoaded. You should also change your "LOAD TYPE" to be "No wrap - in <head>" That way it actually loads.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an eslint error that is informing you that you have defined a function that is not being used.

This is to help you keep your code clean, by pointing out obsolete objects.

Because you are calling this function from the `DOMContentLoaded` handler that is defined in the HTML file, your eslint has no awareness of this.

You can probably just add the event handler definition to the bottom of your script file, and all will work as desired, and your eslint error will go away:

```
function addDnDHandlers() {
    /* ... your code here ... */
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addDnDHandlers, false);
```

Alternatively, you can add directives in your code that will tell eslint to ignore that rule violation in this case.

Ignore this rule in the whole file by adding an ignore directive at the top:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */ (not recommended)
```

... or ignore the rule for a particular line:

```
function addDnDHandlers() { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

You should familiarize yourself with the rules and configurations available in eslint: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/

Comment: Thank you for your help the error is gone but my code is not working properly as it suppose to show added coffee in cart but its dragging fine but not showing ...any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Which method did you use to correct the eslint error? Are there any runtime errors in the console?

Comment: ok so now I have JSlint warnings related to "var" that I have define in beginning of function not any runtime console error but they are warnings about my  var

Comment: missing 'use strict' statement.